# Codeship cannot push image to Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, continuous-delivery, google-cloud-platform

I created a Service Account in the Google Cloud console to let Codeship push Docker images to Google Container Registry, but when I test it with `jet steps --push` it says I don't have permissions.

```
{StepFinished=step_name:"push_app" type:STEP_FINISHED_TYPE_ERROR}                                                                                                                 
Image Push error for image gcr.io/my-project/my-app:1499432530, denied: Unable to access the repository; please check that you have permission to access it
```

The service account already has full owner permissions to my account. Is there anything I need to check in the Google console or my Codeship configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The service account needs permissions to the storage segment where the containers will be pushed. To fix this

- Log in to the Google Cloud Platform console
- Go to the *Storage* section
- Tick the corresponding storage segment and click *Show information panel* button in the top-right corner.
- Add the storage object administration permission to your service account.

You can then retry locally with `jet steps --push`.